# Question regarding piecewise syntax with pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots

The piece function is defined as following:
[image]

Here is the code snippet:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{func}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    (and(#1>=0 , #1<=500)   * (300 + #1*(12/10))   +%
    (and(#1>500, #1<=1000)  *  (600 + #1*(12/10))    %
   }%
}
```

What does the asterisk "*" right after the `(and..` actually do? and the "+" sign at the end. I reused some the examples that I found in this site, but the syntax is not really intuitive. Could anyone explain this syntax? Thanks in advance.

**Edit** (Add complete example)

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{polynomial}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.footprints}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{func}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    (and(#1>=0    ,#1<=500)  * (300 + #1*(12/10))   +%
    (and(#1>=500  ,#1<=1000) * (600 + #1*(12/10))   %
   }%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \begin{axis}
        [title={$C(x)$},
            ylabel=$y$,
            xlabel=$x$,
            grid=both,
            minor xtick={0,100,...,1000},
            xtick={0,200,...,1000},
            ytick={0,400,...,3200}]

        \addplot[blue,domain=0:1000]{func(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that `and(...)` returns 1 when the condition inside is true and 0 when false; `*` denotes multiplication. So, when `#1` is for instance 100, you're doing `1*(300+100*(12/10))+0*(600+100*(12/10))` which is what's expected. When `#1` is 700, the zero and one are reversed.

Comment: @Chan, I think you'd better use two different plot commands for the two pieces of line in order to show the discontinuity. So, you could also set `samples=2` improving the computation time and the file size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simple math. :) But one should know that

```
and(<condition1>,<condition2>)
```

returns 1 when both conditions are true and 0 when at least one is false. So, when `pgf` is computing the value of `func` at 150 it does

```
(and(150>=0 , 150<=500) * (300 + 150*(12/10)) + (and(150>500, 150<=1000) * (600 + 150*(12/10))
```

which becomes

```
1 * (300 + 150*(12/10)) + 0 * (600 + 150*(12/10))
```

that is,

```
(300 + 150*(12/10))
```

When it's evaluating at 725, the same applies, but the result is

```
0 * (300 + 725*(12/10)) + 1 * (600 + 725*(12/10))
```

that is,

```
(600 + 725*(12/10))
```

In both cases the value is what's requested.

You need to correct the input if you want a graph which has an actual step at the discontinuity:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}
  [title={$C(x)$},
   ylabel=$y$,
   xlabel=$x$,
   grid=both,
   minor xtick={0,100,...,1000},
   xtick={0,200,...,1000},
   ytick={0,400,...,3200},
   samples=1000]
  \addplot[blue,domain=0:1000]{func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but the computation time will be longer. Also the function definition should be changed:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{func}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    (and(#1>=0  , #1<500)   * (300 + #1*(12/10)) +
    (and(#1>=500 , #1<=1000) * (600 + #1*(12/10))
  }%
}
```

so that the correct value is computed at 500 (you decide where the `=` should go).

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. By the way, when I modify the first condition to `and(#1>=0 , **#1<500**)` , the graph still looks the same, which is quite odd. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @Chan Please, add a complete example of code.