# Piecewise Function Using Pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Using the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78589/question-regarding-piecewise-syntax-with-pgfplot) I have tried to plot a piecewise function.  My code looks like

```
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{func}{1}{%    
\pgfmathparse{%
(and(#1<=-2)  * (#1*#1 + #1*6 + 8)   +%     
(and(#1>=-2  ,#1<=1) * (2 - #1 - #1*#1)   +%    
(and(#1>=1  ,#1<=2) * (6 - #1*8 + #1*#1*2)   +%
(and(#1>=2) * (-10 + #1*6 - #1*#1)   %
}%
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8    
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=middle, 
axis y line=middle, 
ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,1,2,3,4,5}, ylabel=$y$, 
xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5}, xlabel=$x$
]

\addplot[blue,domain=-5:5]{func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

The function will be x^2+6x+8 for x<=-2, 2-x-x^2 for -2<=x<=1, 2x^2-8x+6 for 1<=x<=2, and -x^2+6x-10 for x>=2.  When I try to compile it gives me a `PGF Math Error: internal routine of the floating point`.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `and` function has at least two arguments, otherwise it can’t `and` anything. Simply remove the `and`s from the first and the last term.

You should also make sure that the pieces do not overlap which they do in your case as you always use `<=` and `>=` on the same border value.

Furthermore, I have used the top-level `declare function` key to declare a function.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\x)= (\x<=-2) * (\x*\x + 6*\x + 8)   +
     and(\x>-2, \x<=1) * (2 - \x - \x*\x)     +
     and(\x>1,  \x<=2) * (6 - 8*\x + 2*\x*\x) +
                (\x>2) * (-10 + 6*\x - \x*\x);
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$y$,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$x$,
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-2, 1, 2}{
  \draw[dashed] ({rel axis cs: 0,0} -| {axis cs: #1, 0}) -- ({rel axis cs: 0,1} -| {axis cs: #1, 0});}
\addplot[blue, domain=-5:5, smooth]{func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Hi, could I ask you how to make this function parametric ? (parameters instead of 6 and 8)

Answer (score 3):

It's for an alternative with Asymptote.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
// ploting a piecewise function
import graph;
unitsize(1cm);
real f(real x){
if (x<=-2) 
  return (x^2 + 6x + 8);
else if (x>-2 && x<=1) 
  return (2-x-x^2);
else if (x>1 && x<=2) 
  return (6 - 8x + 2x^2);
else 
  return (-10+6x-x^2);
}

guide gf=graph(f,-5,4.2);
draw(gf,red+1pt);
xaxis(Label("$x$",align=NE),-4.9,4.9,LeftTicks(Step=1,NoZero),Arrow(TeXHead));
yaxis(Label("$y$",align=E),-2.5,2.5,RightTicks(Step=1,NoZero),Arrow(TeXHead));
//axes("$x$","$y$",Arrow);
```