# Plotting a Function in pgfplots with a Gap in the Domain

Tags: pgfplots

I recently received help plotting the function [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132476/piecewise-function-using-pgfplots).  I would now like to remove a portion of the graph.  I want to remove the part with -2<= x <= 1.  When I comment it out, pgfplots fills in the gap with a straight line.  But, I would like that portion of the graph to disappear entirely and result in a function with a disconnected domain.  Is that possible?

Comment: You can replace the expression for `(-2, 1]` with: `and(\x>-2, \x<=1) * inf` and add `unbounded coords=jump`. Unfortunately, you need to tell `pgfplots` to use the *x* values `-2` and `1` by setting the `samples` value higher (say `samples=400`) or by providing explicit *x* values with `samples at={-5, -4.5, ..., -2, 1, 1.01, 1.5, 2, 2.1, 2.2, ..., 5}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use two `\addplot` commands with different domains such that the region you don't want is excluded.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\x)= (\x<=-2) * (\x*\x + 6*\x + 8)   +
     and(\x>-2, \x<=1) * (2 - \x - \x*\x)     +
     and(\x>1,  \x<=2) * (6 - 8*\x + 2*\x*\x) +
                (\x>2) * (-10 + 6*\x - \x*\x);
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$y$,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5, xtick={-5,...,5}, xlabel=$x$,
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-2, 1, 2}{
  \draw[dashed] ({rel axis cs: 0,0} -| {axis cs: #1, 0}) -- ({rel axis cs: 0,1} -| {axis cs: #1, 0});}
\addplot[blue, domain=-5:-2, smooth]{func(x)};
\addplot[blue, domain=1:5, smooth]{func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]