# Plotting a function in Latex

Tags: plot

How do you draw functions that look like this? I apologize for not providing you with an attempt to solve this problem - I am a second-day user of Latex. Greatly appreciate your help.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document - comment this line to return to the LaTeX default
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\usepackage{xfrac}


\begin{document}
\[ F_x(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    0 & \quad \text{for $x <0$}\\
    x^2 & \quad \text{$0\leq x<0.5$}\\
    1-3(1-x)^2 & \quad \text{$0.5\leq x<1$}\\
    1 & \quad \text{$x\geq 1$}
  \end{array} \right.\]
  \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean you want to plot it? Something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132476/piecewise-function-using-pgfplots?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Plotting a function that has multiple arguments, I guess (?).

Comment: You can use something like pgfplots as the above comment shows but alternatively (and more commonly) you can plot the graph in whatever plotting software you are used to (gnuplot, excel, matlab, ....) and include the resulting image using `\includegraphics`

Comment: But plots produced by matlab and excel are ugly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\[ F_x(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
    0 & \quad \text{for $x <0$}\\
    x^2 & \quad \text{$0\leq x<0.5$}\\
    1-3(1-x)^2 & \quad \text{$0.5\leq x<1$}\\
    1 & \quad \text{$x\geq 1$}
  \end{cases}
  \]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[smooth,samples=200,domain=-2:0]{0};
\addplot[smooth,samples=200,domain=0:0.5]{x^2};
\addplot[smooth,samples=200,domain=0.5:1]{1-3*(1-x)^2};
\addplot[smooth,samples=200,domain=1:2]{1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edited:

Implementing the change suggested by the OP works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\[ F_x(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
    0 & \quad \text{for $x <0$}\\
    2x & \quad \text{$0\leq x<0.5$}\\
    6-6x & \quad \text{$0.5\leq x<1$}\\
    1 & \quad \text{$x\geq 1$}
  \end{cases}
  \]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[smooth,samples=200,domain=-2:0]{0};
\addplot[smooth,samples=200,domain=0:0.5]{2*x};
\addplot[smooth,samples=200,domain=0.5:1]{6-6*x};
\addplot[smooth,samples=200,domain=1:2]{1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edited again to create red lines and dots, as per request:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\[ F_x(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
    0 & \quad \text{for $x <0$}\\
    x^2 & \quad \text{$0\leq x<0.5$}\\
    1-3(1-x)^2 & \quad \text{$0.5\leq x<1$}\\
    1 & \quad \text{$x\geq 1$}
  \end{cases}
  \]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[Red,smooth,samples=200,domain=-2:0]{0};
\addplot[Red,smooth,samples=200,domain=0:0.5]{x^2};
\addplot[Red,smooth,samples=200,domain=0.5:1]{1-3*(1-x)^2};
\addplot[Red,smooth,samples=200,domain=1:2]{1};
\fill[Red] (axis cs:0,0) circle(0.5mm) (axis cs:0.5,0.25) circle(0.5mm) (axis cs:1,1) circle(0.5mm);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not that I am easily impressed...WOW, the graph looks impressive. I will use it as a template for other similar graphs.

Comment: P.S. How do you make this graph thicker?

Comment: Put *very thick,* before *smooth*

Comment: Hey! Thanks again. I tried plotting a different graph by using your template but it didn't work. It was quite strange because I only changed 2 things: x^2 became 2x, and 1-3(1-x)^2 became 6-6x. As you can tell, these are the derivatives. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Hmm.  I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Works fine for me; see edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just checked and it works well. Just on a side note, how do you mark dots on such graphs like Bernard, who responded below, did?

Answer (score 5):

The `pstricks` way. It can be compiled with `pdflatex` if you launch it with the `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX)  or `--shell-escape` (TeXLive, MacTeX) switch:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, svgnames, pdf]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=4cm, linewidth = 0.6pt,  ticksize = -2pt 2pt}
\begin{pspicture*}(-1.6,-0.9)(1.9,1.6)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1.6,-0.9)(1.9,1.6)[ $ x $, -135][ $ y $,-135]%
\uput[d](-0.05,0){0}
{\psset{linestyle = dashed,, linecolor = LightSteelBlue}
\psline(0, 0.25)(0.5, 0.25)(0.5, 0)\uput[d](0.5,0){ $ \mfrac{1}{2} $}\uput[l](0, 0.25){ $ \mfrac{1}{4} $}
\psline(0,1)(1,1)(1,0)}
\psset{linewidth = 1.5pt, linecolor =IndianRed ,plotpoints=50,plotstyle=curve, algebraic, labelsep = 0.5em}
\psline(-1.6,0)(0,0)
\psplot{0}{0.5}{x^2}
\psplot{0.5}{1}{1-3*(1-x)^2}
\psline(1,1)(2,1)
\psdots[dotsize = 3pt](0,0)(0.5, 0.25)(1,1)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the graph is beautiful. I tried it, but the code isn't working for me.

Comment: Do you have any error message? You can compile with `pdflatex`, although it's based on `pstricks` (`pdf` option in \documentclass). I think I forgot you must set the compiler with the  `--shell-escape` switch.

Comment: That's right, I had an error message. How do you set the compiler with the  --shell-escape switch?

Comment: That depends on your editor… Which one do you use?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't work on Mac. I can only explain for TeXmaker or TeX studio. There must be a place where calls to compilers are written. I suppose TeXshop has a configuration menu.