# Drawing Piecewise Graphs in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I have been using LaTeX forever, but strangely just realized I've never had to plot a graph in it. The graph is seen here:

[image]

and the equations are here

[image]

I want to use

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

However I am open to using other packages if you recommend any?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! The subject of piecewise graphs has been asked and answered many times on this site

Comment: E.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132476/95441 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19510/95441

Answer (score 2):

as starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples=60]
\addplot[blue, domain=0:pi] {cos(deg x)-1};
\addplot[green,domain=0:pi] {-sin(deg x)};
%
\addplot[blue, domain=pi:2*pi] {3*cos(deg x)+1};
\addplot[green,domain=pi:2*pi] {-3*sin(deg x)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where `deg` make conversion of argument `x` from radians to degrees (trigonometric functions are defined for degrees).

[image]

Comment: or you can write `x r` it will understand radians context with that, or change the trig format

Comment: @percusse, i simply forgot on this option :-(. thank you very much to remind me :-). but now i make short text, and receive error. i should repeat my test more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Same output as Zarko's nice answer, but really piecewise functions with `ifthenelse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[samples=60]
     \addplot[blue, domain=0:2*pi] {ifthenelse(x<pi,cos(deg x)-1,3*cos(deg x)+1)};
     \addplot[green,domain=0:2*pi] {ifthenelse(x<pi,-sin(deg x),-3*sin(deg x))};
     \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```