# pgfplots: Syntax of Piecewise Defined Functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I read about piecewise defined functions today and saw this post which was actually about something else:

[Label plots in pgfplots without entering coordinates manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12207/label-plots-in-pgfplots-without-entering-coordinates-manually)

This is taken from there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=center,
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis on top=true,
        xmin=-7,
        xmax=7,
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=4,
        clip=false
] 

\addplot[
    mark=none,
    domain=-4:6,
    samples=80,
    red,
    thick,
] {(x<-2)*-2 + (!(x<-2) && (x<3))*x + (!(x<3)) * 3}
    node[pos=0.1,pin=135:{\color{purple}$f(x)=-2$}] {}
    node[pos=0.6,pin=135:{\color{blue}$f(x)=x$}] {}
    node[pos=0.9,pin=135:{\color{green!70!black}$f(x)=3$}] {}
;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I get the syntax `and(<condition1>,<condition2>)` which is explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78589/question-regarding-piecewise-syntax-with-pgfplot) for example but I do not understand the syntax in the example above

```
(x<-2)*-2 + (!(x<-2) && (x<3))*x + (!(x<3)) * 3
```

Can somebody explain it  to me or am I just being blind? There is no `and` like in `and(a,b)` and what does the `!` do? I guess it's a negation.

**Update**

Can I find this somewhere in a documentation or is this just common knowledge?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `pgfmath` a true expression has the value 1, and a false expression has the value 0.  That is, an expression such as `(x<-2)` is equivalent to a function f(x):

[image]

Hence, this works because:

1. `(x<-2)`: This condition is ONLY true for `x < -2`. Hence this only contributes to the expression for `x < -2`. Hence `(x<-2)*-2=-2` for `x<-2`, 0 otherwise.
2. `(!(x<-2) && (x<3))`: This has the value 1 for `-2 <= x <= 2`. Hence, in this range, this has the value of `x`.
3. `!(x<3)`: This is 1 only for `x >=3`. Hence `(!(x<3)) * 3=3` for `x >=3`, and zero otherwise.

If there is still any confusion,  this table that computes the values of the various conditions should help:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So **(x < 2)** is something like **if(x < 2)**? No keyword needed? Can I find this somewhere in a **documentation** or is this just common knowledge?

Comment: @ManuelKuehner you could think of it as if(x<2) then that expression is 1 otherwise it is 0.

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, you can find documentation about this in the `pgf` manual, section "Mathematical Expressions" in part VIII.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be boolean logic.

So the `&&` is the operator for `and` and the `!` is a negation operator.

So put `x = 1`, then

`(x<-2)*-2`

is `1 < -2` ? No, OK then it's `0`.

`0*-2 = 0`.

And the `!`

`!(x<-2)`

same thing as above but this time negate the result, so a `0` becomes a `1` and a `1` becomes a `0`

and so on...

Here is some information on how boolean logic works

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/truth-table-for-logical-operations.html